# value_counts() AND COMBINE TWO ROWS IN PANDA JYPUTER NOTEBOOK PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data in excel file. here is a sample data and image.

```
In[1] import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'T1': ['A', 'B', 'A'], 
                   'T1_data': [3, 2, '3K'],
                  'T2': ['B', 'A', 'B'], 
                   'T2_data': ["5,2K", 4, 2],
                  
                  })
df

Out[1]  T1  T1_data   T2    T2_data
    0   A     3       B      5,2K
    1   B     2       A       4
    2   A     3K      B       2
```

**expected outputs :**

```
i want this

  T1_count   T1_count  T2_count  T2_data
    
A   2         3, 3k        1       4

B   1          2           2      5, 2k
```

and this

```
    T12_count    T12_data
    
A      3         3, 3K, 4

B      3         2, 5, 2.
```

I know simple value_counts() but i don't know how can i do above things. if anyone can help it would be really appriciated.

```
df1 = df['T1'].value_counts()
df1

A    2
B    1
Name: T1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Please provide your sample input and output  in the text of your question, not as a picture or link. See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). PLease also include a [mcve] with _code_ for what you've tried so far, and what went wrong with your attempt(s)

Comment: Thank you for sharing links. i have changed question accordingly. @G.Anderson